# How to transfer data from wide format to long format in Excel Or SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a data like shown below.Any idea how to convert from wide format to long format in Excel Or SQL.

```
ID       TOTAL    SCORE   PLAYER
34543    12342     456    45
45632    34521     241    33
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID        DATA_TYPE   VALUE
34543      TOTAL      12342
34543      SCORE      34521
34543      PLAYER     45
45632      TOTAL      34521
45632      SCORE      241
45632      PLAYER      33
```

Answer (score 6):

My preferred method for unpivoting is to use `apply`:

```
select t.id, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('TOTAL', total), ('SCORE', score), ('PLAYER', player)
     ) v(DATA_TYPE, VALUE);
```

In addition to being rather concise, this is a good introduce to lateral joins.  This is a very powerful construct in SQL, useful for many other purposes (unlike `UNPIVOT`).  It also scans the table only once, so it is more efficient than `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Since OP didn't mention which version of SQL, I think this only works in 2012 or later?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `UNPIVOT` in your query. Try this:

```
--sample data
declare @t table (id int, total int, score int, player int)
insert into @t values
(34543, 12342, 456, 45),
(45632, 34521, 241, 33)
--query that will return deisred result
select Id, Data_Type, Value from (
    select * from @t
) [t] unpivot (
    VALUE for DATA_TYPE in (total, score, player)
) [u]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT distinct ID, 'TOTAL' AS DATA_TYPE, TOTAL AS VALUE
    FROM Your_Table
    UNION
    SELECT distinct ID, 'SCORE' AS DATA_TYPE, SCORE AS VALUE
    FROM Your_Table
    UNION
    SELECT distinct ID, 'PLAYER' AS DATA_TYPE, PLAYER AS VALUE
    FROM Your_Table) as tbl
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel is 2010 or later, you can use Power Query (aka Get & Transform in Excel 2016) and unpivot all except the ID column.

Easily done from the GUI

or

**Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"TOTAL", Int64.Type}, {"SCORE", Int64.Type}, {"PLAYER", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```